# AWS RDS SSL connection with FastAPI SQLAlchemy

Tags: postgresql, asynchronous, sqlalchemy, amazon-rds, fastapi

I have to connect to AWS RDS using SQLAlchemy using SSL connection, but I am getting error
`asyncpg.exceptions.InvalidAuthorizationSpecificationError: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "106.213.85.14", user "user", database "db-name", no encryption       make: *** [Makefile:85: migration] Error 1`

URL: `postgresql+asyncpg://username:password@aws-endpoint:port/db-name?rds_sslrootcert=true&sslmode=require`

The following code for connection asynchronously is:

```
if settings.DB_SSL:
    ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context(cafile=settings.RDS_CERT_PATH)
    ssl_context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
    connect_args = {"ssl": ssl_context}


engine = create_async_engine(
    settings.DB_SSL_DSN if settings.DB_SSL else settings.DB_DSN,
    echo=settings.DB_ECHO,
    pool_size=settings.DB_POOL_SIZE,
    max_overflow=settings.DB_MAX_OVERFLOW,
    future=True,
    connect_args=connect_args if settings.DB_SSL else None,
)

async_session = sessionmaker(engine, expire_on_commit=False, class_=AsyncSession, future=True)
```

In the RDS Security Group, I have kept all the traffic incoming available as well, still getting this error.

Please let me know what could be the possible mistake on my side.

Comment: Are you following some tutorial or documentation?  I've don't think I've ever seen rds_sslrootcert before.

Comment: I followed some of the resources online and trying to run the same thing using psql it's getting connected but using SQLAlchemy it isn't.

Comment: Can you link to the resources?  We can't tell if they are just bad, or if you are misunderstanding them, without being able to see them.  I believe asyncpg does not use libpq, which means it is quite different than `psql` both in capabilities and in defaults, and in configuration.  psql defaults to using SSL, but not verifying the signature.  Based on the error, it seems your asyncpg setup is not even trying to use SSL.